# How to create a ZipFile from a byte array in Java

Tags: java, zip

In Java you have to do 
    new ZipFile(new File("xxx.zip"));
to unzip a zip file.

Now I get a byte array whose content is a zip file. I get this byte array from database instead of a file. I would like to unzip this "byte array file" but there is no ZipFile constructor for byte array or String (I mean the content instead of the file path).

Is there any solution? (Of course I do not want to write this byte array to an actual file and read it into memory again.)

Thanks!

Comment: so your byte array contains a zipped file and you want to extract it , right ???

Comment: You can use a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) instead.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Yes, it's content is exactly a zip file compressing a file with a specific name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a ByteArrayInputStream inside the ZipInputStream which is created from a byte array

```
byte[] ba;

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
InputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
```

Use zis to read the contents uncompressed

Answer (score 0):

Implementations of `ZipFile` requires it to be a file. Memory mapping may be used, for instance. In general it is assumed that the archive may be huge.

As @Perception mentions, `ZipInputStream` can be used to read sequentially through the stream. Third-party libraries may be available to replace `ZipFile`.